# php emailing an array

Tags: php, email

I am trying to email the results held in an array ( shopping cart ) however when I send the email it is only the first name, price and qty which is displayed in the email and not any of the other names, prices or qty's. I am assuming there is something wrong with my loop but not sure where. Many thanks in advance.  The results are placed in the comma_separated variable

```
$result= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM testtable  ");

// save product list as array

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) 
{
$sku = $row->ProductSKU;
$productInfo[$sku] = array();
$productInfo[$sku]['Name'] = $row->Name;
$productInfo[$sku]['Price'] = $row->Price;
$productInfo[$sku]['QTY'] = $row->QTY;
}
} else {
die ("ERROR");
}

$i=0;
$total=0;
// print the currently selected items
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $sku => $quantity) {


$subtotal = $quantity * $productInfo[$sku]['Price'];
$total += $subtotal;
$array = array("Product:".$productInfo[$sku]['Name'],
"Units @".$productInfo[$sku]['Price'] ,
"Total:".number_format($subtotal, 2));
$comma_separated = implode("\n", $array);
}
```

Comment: Where are you using `$comma_separated`?

Comment: I'm going to guess that you need to concatenate the result onto `$comma_separated`, as it's being over-written every time in your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably change the following code:

```
// print the currently selected items
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $sku => $quantity) {


$subtotal = $quantity * $productInfo[$sku]['Price'];
$total += $subtotal;
$array = array("Product:".$productInfo[$sku]['Name'],
"Units @".$productInfo[$sku]['Price'] ,
"Total:".number_format($subtotal, 2));
$comma_separated = implode("\n", $array);
}
```

into:

```
// print the currently selected items

$comma_separated = array();

foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $sku => $quantity) {


$subtotal = $quantity * $productInfo[$sku]['Price'];
$total += $subtotal;
$array = array("Product:".$productInfo[$sku]['Name'],
"Units @".$productInfo[$sku]['Price'] ,
"Total:".number_format($subtotal, 2));

 $comma_separated[] = implode(', ',$array);
}
$comma_separated = implode("\n", $comma_separated);
```

Earlier you have created product array, imploded it using new line but finally you haven't saved this array in any other variable, so each time you run foreach loop you initialized `$comma_separated` variable again so the previous value wasn't there.

Now you should append `$comma_separated` to mail content, for example:

```
$mail_content .= $comma_separated;
```

Comment: sorry im new to php my body of the email is this $body=wordwrap(" Order received $comma_separated",70,"\r\n"); do you mean this should now be $body=wordwrap(" Order received $mail_content",70,"\r\n");

Comment: No, what you showed here should work fine now: `$body=wordwrap(" Order received $comma_separated",70,"\r\n");`

Comment: it still only displays the last product, price and qty :(

Comment: So you should check what is the value of  `$_SESSION['cart']`. Probably you have only one single product in this variable and that's why the result is only one product

Comment: I had the } at the bottom in the wrong place of the code which followed it. Thank you very much for you patience.